# Pandas Retrieve value from last [-kth] column before null

Tags: python, pandas

How can I iterate through my rows in a dataframe and just retrieve the value nth columns before the last non-null column. My initial thoughs is to use a form of iterrows to go through each row but have not used that function very often. So the dataframe I have looks like this:

```
      one     two   three   four   five
a  1.1770 -0.8547  0.3497 1.3690    nan
b  0.3200 -1.6833  0.7674    nan    nan
c  0.0053 -0.3656 -0.6696    nan    nan
d  0.6170 -0.4473     nan    nan    nan
e -0.4072 -0.0763  0.0998 0.6189    nan
f -0.4753 -0.7615 -1.5959 0.3822 0.6244
```

And I want to create a new column as follows (based on n = -2 from end)

```
    six
a  0.3497
b -1.6833
c -0.3656
d  0.6170
e  0.0998
f -1.5959
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `apply` to remove the nulls and take the integer location like this.

```
In [176]: df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[-2], axis=1)
Out[176]: 
a    0.3497
b   -1.6833
c   -0.3656
d    0.6170
e    0.0998
f    0.3822
dtype: float64
```